# Using cv::glob for multiple extensions

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use [cv::glob](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaf91b7f383218e2d3f760939140942297) to find images in a folder system. What I now want is to search for multiple file extensions at once (let's say .jpg and .png). Is there a way to do this?

The [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaf91b7f383218e2d3f760939140942297) on this method doesn't specify the `pattern` parameter.

At the moment I'm using the ugly and inefficient method of searching for each extension seperately and combining the results. See:

```
vector<cv::String> imageNames;
vector<string> allowedExtensions = { ".jpg", ".png" };
for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.size(); i++) {
    vector<cv::String> imageNamesCurrentExtension;
    cv::glob(
        inputFolder + "*" + allowedExtensions[i],
        imageNamesCurrentExtension,
        true
    );
    imageNames.insert(
        imageNames.end(),
        imageNamesCurrentExtension.begin(),
        imageNamesCurrentExtension.end()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Open CV` or even OS file system API has no build-in way to do that. You can improve your code by eliminating multiple iteration over the folder/folders. For example you can use [`boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator) and some filter function to retrieve all the files in a single iteration.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <set>

namespace fs = ::boost::filesystem;

void GetPictures(const fs::path& root, const std::set<string>& exts, vector<fs::path>& result)
{
  if(!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root)) 
  {
    return;
  }

  fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
  fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;
  while(it != endit)
  {
    if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && exts.find(it->path().extension()) != exts.end()) 
    {
      result.push_back(it->path());
    }
    ++it;
  }
}
```

It's only a sample, you should take care of string casing, error handling, etc.